# SAML stopped working after update to Artifactory 5.3.1

Tags: upgrade, saml, artifactory

We've used Artifactory 5.2.0 until today and had SAML configured and working. I just upgraded and now it doesn't work anymore. I'm being redirected to 
https://MY_URL/artifactory/webapp/saml/loginResponse
which is not found.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about this on the Artifactory site - can anyone help?

I do not have access to ADFS directory unfortunately - we have an external partner for those kinds of things. But they told me that they haven't changed anything in their configuration.

Login into Artifactory works, also with LDAP and the new version works fine - except that one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an ADFS patch was the problem and the message Artifactory got wasn't correct so obviously the login didn't work anymore. Unfortunately I didn't really get an error message that would have led me on the right path.

We fixed the ADFS, got a new certificate and now it's working again!